# Calling unlock on mutex when it's not locked?

Tags: c++, locking, mutex

I have an if-branch like so:

```
  MLOCK.lock();
  if (CPRIMES[snode->cid] == snode) {
    CPRIMES.erase(snode->cid);
    log("[remove_storage_node] Node " + kv_addr + " dropped as primary", VB);
    MLOCK.unlock();
    elect_new_primary(snode->cid);
  }
  MLOCK.unlock();
```

I want to make sure that the lock is unlocked is before the call to `elect_new_primary` and also at the end of the code block. Is this bad practice? What's a better way of ensuring the lock is unlocked this way?

Comment: Did you try what happens? I'd recommend using [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard)s instead.

Answer (score 4):

This answer assumes `MLOCK` refers to a standard mutex object [`std::mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex).

From [`std::mutex::unlock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock) :

> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Therefore, your code has Undefined Behavior when it tries to unlock an unlocked mutex.

These kinds of problems are best solved by using the standard class [`std::unique_lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock). This class will manage the lock and, when its own lifetime ends, it will make sure to unlock the mutex if it is still locked.

For example :

```
#include <mutex>

std::mutex m;

void foo(bool b)
{
    // Lock `m` and take ownership of that lock
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{m};

    if(b) { 
        // Unlocks `m`
        lock.unlock();
    }
}   // `m` will be unlocked if it wasn't unlocked previously
```

You should very rarely resort to directly calling the `lock` or `unlock` member functions of a `mutex` object.

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/unlock):

> std::mutex::unlock
> Unlocks the mutex.
> The mutex must be locked by the current thread of execution, otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

So no, you must not do it.  Instead, you must keep track of whether you locked it, either by using [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or some other way.